# Can someone suggest me important references for deriving EOM in MCSCF?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, reference-request, ab-initio

I am currently starting a project dealing with MCSCF method. Can someone please give me references (papers or lecture notes are preferred) which may be considered as the "corner stones" in the history of the development of this method for atoms (for molecule is fine but the for atom will be nice)? I have searched and in fact obtained some papers which look important in this subject but since MCSCF is very popular I am sure there are already loads of papers of various purposes published within the subject, making locating the most important ones difficult. I am also looking for the derivation of the equation of motion (EOM) of the orbitals and coefficients.

Currently I am reading "[Computational Atomic Structure - An MCHF Approach](https://www.crcpress.com/Computational-Atomic-Structure-An-MCHF-Approach/Froese-Fischer-Brage-Johnsson/p/book/9780750304665)" by C. Froesche-Fischer and "[The Hartree-Fock Methods for Atoms - A Numerical Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047125990X)" also by the same author. But from the terminology the author adopts it looks like these books is not the typical literature a quantum chemistry lecturer would recommend his students to read.

Comment: The best way to start learning about MCSCF is to consult a standard text book (a selection can be found in our [resources for learning chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37303/4945) thread) and follow the citations within. It is possible that the community will regard your question as too broad (or even a duplicate of the linked post). For [tag:reference-request]s, you should be very specific, also outlining what you have read so far, found so far.

Comment: Currently I am reading "Computational Atomic Structure - An MCHF Approach" by C. Froesche-Fischer and "The Hartree-Fock Methods for Atoms - A Numerical Approach" also by the same author.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and include any and all information you have obtained to make it complete and standalone as comments are not meant to last forever.